# RxSwift Driver gets disposed after first value

Tags: swift, cocoa, rx-swift

I've just started playing around with Rx and decided to try out making a simple OSX app using RxSwift.

Since my app has a login form, I've found that [GithubSignup example](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingDriver) is pretty similar to what I'm doing.

I'm, however having an issue that my `Drivers` get disposed after first value is emitted from them, and I can't figure out how or why. Since my code is really similar to one from the Github example, I must be overlooking something.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
class LoginVM {

    let isWorking: Driver<Bool>
    let loginEnabled: Driver<Bool>

    init(
        input: (
            email: Driver<String>,
            password: Driver<String>,
            loginRequests: Driver<Void>
        ),
        dependency: (
            RoundedClient
        )
    ) {
        self.isWorking = Variable(false).asDriver()

        let credentials = Driver
            .combineLatest(input.email, input.password){ (email: $0, password: $1) }

        let credentialsEmpty = credentials
            .map{ credentials in
                credentials.email.characters.count > 0 && credentials.password.characters.count > 0
            }
            .distinctUntilChanged()

        self.loginEnabled = Driver
            .combineLatest(credentialsEmpty, self.isWorking){ !($0 || $1) }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
    }

}
```

And here is my ViewController:

```
class LoginViewController: NSViewController {

    var screenManager: ScreenManager!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginSpinner: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: NSTextField!

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vm = LoginVM(
            input: (
                email: self.emailField.rx_text.asDriver(),
                password: self.passwordField.rx_text.asDriver(),
                loginRequests: self.loginButton.rx_tap.asDriver()
            ),
            dependency: RoundedClient.sharedInstance
        )

        vm.loginEnabled
            .driveNext{ [weak self] enabled in
                self?.loginButton.enabled = enabled
                self?.loginButton.alphaValue = enabled ? 1.0 : 0.5
            }.addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

        vm.isWorking
            .drive(self.loginSpinner.ex_animating)
            .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
    }

}
```

Here is an example when I attach ".debug()" to `credentialsEmpty` driver on `LoginVM`:

```
2016-04-17 16:32:36.730: LoginViewController.swift:38 (init(input:dependency:)) -> subscribed
2016-04-17 16:32:36.731: LoginViewController.swift:38 (init(input:dependency:)) -> Event Next(false)
2016-04-17 16:32:39.081: LoginViewController.swift:38 (init(input:dependency:)) -> Event Next(true)
2016-04-17 16:32:39.081: LoginViewController.swift:38 (init(input:dependency:)) -> disposed
```

It is getting disposed as soon as value is emitted after initial one.

Answer (score 1):

move your LoginVM instance variable to class member field.

> let vm = LoginVM( ...

above 'vm' instance has locality in viewDidLoad() function

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I wrote

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

inside the `viewDidLoad` method.
Which effectively brought it out of scope as soon as the method finished.